# Getting an API error when trying to launch a static google map

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets

1. I am trying to execute a static map from a cell on a google sheet via a google script.  My end goal is to load my own map (contained in a .kmz that was downloaded from google my maps) and display a pin to locate a user-defined zone (colored polygon on map).

I have an API key already set up from previous mapping tasks.

```
function getZone() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;

  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var address = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();

  var testMap = Maps.newStaticMap().addMarker(address);

  ss.getRange("B1").setValue(testMap.getMapUrl());
}
```

I then receive this error when I click on the link in my spreadsheet:

The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

Comment: How are you including the key in the Static Map URL?

Comment: I am not including the API key anywhere at the moment.  I am not sure where to add it.

Comment: Where/How is your spreadsheet creating the URL for the Static Map? (The key goes in that URL)

Comment: I have an address in cell A1.  After I run the script it places the URL in cell B1 via the "ss.getRange("B1").setValue(testMap.getMapUrl());".  When I try to use the link in the spreadsheet it gives me the Error message.

Comment: What does `getMapUrl` do?  What does it return (you might be able to concatenate the key to that)

Comment: This is the value of A1 131 Broadview Avenue Warrenton VA

Comment: This is the value of A2  http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=512x512&markers=131+Broadview+Avenue+Warrenton+VA  I tried to add the API like this ss.getRange("B1").setValue(testMap.getMapUrl()+ "xxxAPIKEYZZZ"); but that did not work.

Comment: it should be +`"&key="+YOUR_API_KEY` (so the final URL is `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=512x512&markers=131+Broadview+Avenue+Warrenton+VA&key=YOUR_API_KEY`)

Comment: That worked, thanks.  Do you have any experience with adding .kmz file to a map with google script and then plotting an address?  I have downloaded a map that I customized in a .kmz file from google my maps.  I need to plot the address that is located on the spreadsheet onto a map that contains my custom polygons (zones for a business).  I am curious if I can call that map (if I made it public) instead of the static one the getMapUrl was using.  Any thoughts?

Comment: That is another question.

Answer (score 1):

That error means you need to append the API key to the static map URL.

it should be the existing URL +`"&key="+YOUR_API_KEY`

The final URL should be (for your example):

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=512x512&markers=131+Broadview+Avenue+Warrenton+VA&key=YOUR_API_KEY)
```