# Using python to access web data

Tags: python, json

I run this code in python using json

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import ssl

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE




serviceurl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

#serviceurl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

while True:
    address = input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1: break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address': address})
    print('Retrieving', url)

    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read().decode()
    print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')

    try:
        js = json.loads(data)
    except:
        js = None

    if not js or 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
        print(data)
        continue

    print(json.dumps(js, indent=4))

    lat = js['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
    lng = js['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']
    print('lat', lat, 'lng', lng)
    location = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
    print(location)
```

I copied this above code from the course on coursera (using python to access web data)
how can I fix this error because It is my first time working with json.

```
You Must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps platform APIs "
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an API error when trying to launch a static google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662706/getting-an-api-error-when-trying-to-launch-a-static-google-map)

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine you'll want to take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key) into getting yourself an API key to access Google's geocoding API.